# Is there a way to force Visual studio 2017 to accept a CMAKE 2.8.12.2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

So I am trying to build a basic C++ project on our university Linux server.
I went and checked the CMake version on the server, it is 2.8.12.2

- I love using Visual Studio, so i tried using Visual Studio after SSH into my university server to build a basic hello world program on it.
- I got the following message in my Visual Studio 2017:
  CMake 3.8.x or above is not available on the remote system. See https://aka.ms/linuxcmakeconfig for more info
- Is there a way to forcibly make Visual Studio accept a lower version of CMake 2.8.12.2
- I made changes to the `CMakeLists.txt` as follows:
  `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12.2)`.

But still Visual Studio was complaining about not having CMake version 3.8 in the University server.

I've attached the screen shots below:
[image]

- I was told to use some IDE called CLion. But I know Visual Studio is the better option, having used it all my life in the real world/non-university setting.

Comment: "Better" being 100% subjective. CLion is a perfectly capable IDE.

Comment: I can't even find documentation for cmake versions older than 3.0 on the cmake web site. 2.8 is seriously outdated. I'd put a bug in someone's ear about updating.

Comment: @Shawn The documentation is there, but in a less convenient format, see "Older Reference Documentation" on this page: https://cmake.org/documentation/ @ wsr007 The problem with older cmake versions is that VS code does require cmake to generate additional information. If you want to use this old version,you'll need to invoke the cmake command line tool manually or though VS Code specific functionality and the IDE may be missing some info.The alternative would be to set up a environment that is as close to the university machine as possible and developing locally only transfering the end result

Comment: @fabian Thanks for the Cmake documentation. I will check it out and see where it takes me eventually. (Can't resit a challenge).  Yes as you said, for now I will just debug compile and build my programs in Visual Studio. Before pasting it into Clion which I already setup to SSH and build on the university machine  for the final build and push.  If I succeeded in setting up things based on the documentation you sent. I'll paste the answer here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

No, it's not possible.

### Reason

The Visual Studio 2017 documentation states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/cmake-linux-project?view=msvc-150):

> The CMake support in Visual Studio requires server mode support introduced in CMake 3.8.

This means VS requires the [cmake-server(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-server.7.html) API to query information like where CMake puts the built binaries, what include paths are used, etc. Without this information, VS would not be able to provide all the useful features of an IDE such as debugging, include path checks/auto-completion, etc. So there is no way, the CMake integration of VS (or any other IDE like CLion) is going to work with an CMake version that does not provide the server mode yet, which is definitely the case for all 2.x versions.

### More Background

The server mode was actually [introduced in CMake 3.7](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.7.html). I don't know why the VS docs suggest it's 3.8 ‍♂️. But I guess that's not an important difference for your case anyway.
Newer versions of Visual Studio (since 2019) even use the more recent [cmake-file-api(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html) introduced in CMake 3.14 as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/cmake-linux-project?view=msvc-160):

> Cmake version 3.14 or later should be installed on the target machine.

The server mode was even deprecated in 3.15 and completely removed in 3.20 in favor of the file-based API.

The VS devs even maintain their own CMake fork: [github.com/microsoft/CMake](https://github.com/microsoft/CMake).
This is because the server mode didn't provide them all the information they needed, as stated in their [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-3-14-and-performance-improvements):

> One of the differences in our CMake fork on github was the backtrace information needed for our Targets View feature inside Visual Studio. Prior to CMake 3.14 we needed the CMake version from our fork, in order for Targets View to work properly. Now, with the file-based API this is no longer required.

So maybe with VS 2017 you should use a CMake binary built by Microsoft. For VS 2019+ the "stock" CMake should probably be fine. As of now, they still maintain their fork, but I haven't found any source that indicates you're required to use it. Probably because Microsoft has become more involved in the CMake development the last couple of years and contributes to the upstream repository as well, e.g. [cmake-presets(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) is the result of a cooperation between Microsoft and Kitware.

### Recommended Solution

As @Shawn already commented, CMake 2.8.12 is seriously outdated (released 2013-10-08) and the best solution would be to ask the admin of your University to update CMake to a more recent version. This has the additional advantage, that you can use and benefit from the ["Modern CMake"](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake) techniques.